# How to configure host only adapter for solaris 11 guest in virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, solaris-11

Usually when I create a new Linux VM I enable 2 adapters in the virtual machine, the first one connected to NAT (for the internet), and the second to the Host Only Network adapter so I can ssh to the VM. In the OS I usually leave them both as dhcp.

I'm attempting to do the same configuration with solaris 11, yet I cannot ping or ssh to the VM from the host (windows 8 btw). First I tried using the Automatic profile configuration, and enabling the net1 interface (the one connected to host only network adapter), but it hangs and spits this error out:

[image]

Then I tried using the DefaultFixed profile and manually configure both interfaces but in that case I couldn't even ping google nor the VM from the host.

I don't know what I'm missing here. I googled but found nothing helpful. I found [this guy tutorial](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=62459), yet it seems for him everything went out of the box when he installed solaris and also he is using a bridge adapter instead of the NAT.

Cheers,

Comment: https://notebookbft.wordpress.com/2016/09/22/configuring-network-for-solaris-11-in-virtual-box/#more-439

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered what was the problem. Turns out there was 2 virtual box host-only adapters configured, one of them had no DHCP server active, just needed to change the adapter to the default one and everything went fine.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the host-only adapter that this VM is connected to does not have an active DHCP server.

You can check this from the main VirtualBox window with File > Preferences > Network > Host-only Networks

Then select the network your VM is attached to in the list. Click the screwdriver icon to open the Host-only Network Details dialog and check the DHCP Server tab.

The checkbox "Enable Server" should be checked and the IP adresses of the server and the address pool should be filled out.

Comment: Checked! It is working, actually I have another linux vm which is using the DHCP server for that adapter and it works fine.

Comment: What is the output of `netadm list` and `ipadm show-if`? Is it possible to assign a fixed IP to `net1`? Can you then ping between the VM and the host (and vice versa)?